# T-SQL : separating datetime into date and time and then converting to numeric

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

My requirement is much more specific than what I found - I have a table that stores a datetime value. I need to retrieve that value, separate it into a date and a time, and then convert both those values into integer values. This is the field I'm trying to retrieve:

```
release_date = 2016-06-28 07:04:17.960
```

This needs to be split like so:

```
--numeric date as yyyymmdd from above value would be:
@my_numeric_date = 20160628

--numeric time as hhmmss from above value would be:
@my_numeric_time = 70417
```

Is there a relatively straightforward way of achieving this?

Comment: Are you sure this is what you want to do? It will be annoying to convert it back to DT, and if you want an INT i'd consider using just the number of seconds since POSIX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last time I needed this, I used these two statements:

```
CONVERT(INTEGER, CONVERT(VARCHAR, release_date, 112)),
CONVERT(INTEGER, REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR, release_date, 108), ':', ''))
```

So, to save it in variables use:

```
SELECT 
@my_numeric_date = CONVERT(INTEGER, CONVERT(VARCHAR, release_date, 112)),
@my_numeric_time = CONVERT(INTEGER, REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR, release_date, 108), ':', ''))
```

Comment: plus-1 I'm withdrawing my answer

Answer (score 1):

```
Declare @Date DateTime = GetDate()

Select DateInt = (Year(@Date)*10000)+(Month(@Date)*100)+Day(@Date)
      ,TimeInt = (DatePart(HH,@Date)*10000)+(DatePart(MINUTE,@Date)*100)+DatePart(SECOND,@Date)
```

Returns

```
DateInt     TimeInt
20160628    104510
```

> -- The DateTime was 2016-06-28 10:45:10.017